# How to call a function without resulting in the loop called

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
def make_album():
    album1 = {}
    album2 = {}
    album3 = {}
    for x in range(3):
        album_nm = input("Album name: ")
        artist_nm = input("Artist name: ")
        if x == 0:
            album1[album_nm] = artist_nm
        elif x == 1:
            album2[album_nm] = artist_nm
        elif x == 2:
            album3[album_nm] = artist_nm
    return album1, album2, album3
make_album()
print(make_album())
```

When I launch the code through a terminal it asks me to input the album_name and the `artist_name` 6 times even though I asked in `range` to be called only 3 times. I've discovered this error is because of the for loop whom gets launched even if I have not called the function which it's a part from `make_album()`. I don't want the loop within the `make_album()` function to be called, so it will ask me to input the data asked for three times only as I've asked in `range(3)`.

Comment: You are calling `make_album()` twice, each call resulting in three sets of inputs.  The first call is completely useless, since you throw away the results.

Comment: OK, I see. I thought the call inside print(make_album()), was just to output the results. Thank yee now, I understand quite well ;D

Comment: **@Youssef**, just remove 2nd last line from your code. Keep last line and you're done. Making 2 function calls is asking you input  `3*2 = 6` times.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the last two lines of your code

```
make_album()
print(make_album())
```

You called the function `make_album()` twice, that's why you got 6 times inputs. Simply change to:

```
result = make_album()
print(result)
```

or, just remove the second last line:

```
print(make_album())
```

good luck, 好运

Answer (score 0):

More pythonic code:

```
def make_album():
    albums = []
    for x in range(3):
        print(x+1)
        album_nm = input("Album name: ")
        artist_nm = input("Artist name: ")
        albums.append({album_nm: artist_nm})
    return albums
albums = make_album()
print(albums)
```